# Adding `fa fa search` right to the textbox

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

UPDATE CODE:

After adding the suggested `<span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>` this is what is rendering now:

[image]

I try to use `style="margin-left:200px;"` but did not do anything

UPDATE END

How to add `fa fa search` on the right side of a textbox? here is my html after it render the code:

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Search </label>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-left:210px">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
        <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" data-jqui-acomp-delay="200" data-jqui-acomp-hiddenvalue="PartId" data-jqui-acomp-minlength="2" data-jqui-acomp-source="/Search" data-jqui-type="autocomplete" id="Part" name="Part" placeholder="Search..." required="required" style="width:215px !important;" type="text" value="" data-parsley-id="6454" autocomplete="off">
        <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-6454"></ul>
        <input id="PartId" name="PartId" type="hidden" value="" data-parsley-id="9361">
        <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-9361"></ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

If i just add the `span` right next to the textbox this is what it renders:

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post your CSS please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for (moving the span after the input and making sure the icon span is inside the input-group-addon span)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>
```

View this code here.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

That should do what you're looking for just add the fa icon where the $ is

Also,
You Should Try using Gylphicons instead

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: I have updated my question, I can not change since this app is in prod,

Comment: Is there any possibility that you gave the Fa-Icon, or the bar, anything in the area a custom class, and gave that class a margin left or negative right?  For testing purposes could you take out  ""width:215px !important;" I find when theres formating problems on my stuff its usually due to me overwriting bootstrap somewhere.

Comment: I have same exact copy of what I have posted above and I do not have any custom class but I have style that you have seen other than that its same exact copy.... even after I removed the `width:215px !important;` still the same behaviour